# Calculate the cardinality and the probability

Tags: probability

Can someone help me with the following task out of my practice book?

> In a competition, $20$ people were drawn who can now win Grand prizes. Among these persons are Mr. Meier and Mr. Müller. Five cars with different colors are available. Now the winner of each car is selected by drawing without replacement from an urn containing $20$ pieces of paper the names of the selected persons.

A: "Mr. Meier and Mr. Müller each win a car”

Calculate the cardinality of A as well as P(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have $5$ possibilities to choose the car which Mr. Meier wins, and then $4$ possibilities for the car that Mr. Müller wins. Then there are $18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16$ possibilities for the winners of the three remaining cars. Consequently:
$$∣A∣ = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 = 97920$$
Since $(\Omega, p)$ is a Laplace experiment, it follows
$$P(A) = \frac{∣A∣}{∣\Omega∣} = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16}{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16} = \frac{1}{19}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.